# Android: AVD-Settings for Galaxy S3Mini

Tags: android, device, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile, galaxy

Please help me to find a virtual device for Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini. It is not available in Genymotion and I do not have a real device to run. I am stuck in an issue regarding this particular mobile users so please help me out of this problem.

Comment: Why don't you check it's spec at a site like gsmarena and define avd with same spec?

Comment: I made an avd referring to gsm arena site but its too slow with the exact specification

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not all Emulators are available in Genymotion. You can easily download samsung galaxy s3 mini emulator example from developer android samsung site and then install it and create one with AVD Manager

Comment: sir i visited the website but all devices are available except samsung galaxy s3 mini..

Comment: Then you have to wait till it appear there. Thats typical Android)

Comment: Is there any other way to find a solution for this?

Comment: The only way is to look at phone characteristics and create same or similar at Genymotion or AVD Manager